# Entity Framework 5.0 ValidateOnSaveEnabled not working?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    if (!this.Set<TEntity>().Local.Any(d => d.Id == entity.Id))
    {
        this.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
    }
    this.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    SaveChanges();
    this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
}
```

The code above throw an exception on the SaveChanges().

```
[DbUpdateException: Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Name'.]
```

How can I remove the validation when removing an Entity?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the problem but if you are deleting entity using a stub object then try setting the `DbEntityEntry.State` to deleted instead. I'm unsure if you even need to turn `validateOnSaveEnabled` off.

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    TEntity alreadyAttached = this.Set<TEntity>().Local
                                  .FirstOrDefault(d=>d.Id == entity.Id);
    if(alreadyAttached != null) entity = alreadyAttached;
    this.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    SaveChanges();
    this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
 }
```

**Edit**

What is written above is may not be entirely correct. As pointed out by Pawel it is a `DbUpdateException` not `DbEntityValidationException`. The reason that the above may work for you is the handling of the case if the entity is attached.

```
if(!this.Set<TEntity>().Local.Any(d=>d.Id == entity.Id))
{
    this.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
}
this.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
```

Consider the case here if the entity is already attached. Not the passed instance of entity (you are just comparing ids) but another instance representing the same entity. Now consider if you have modified this other entity somewhere in code before this point, it would be tracked by the context as modified. You then attempt to remove your passed instance of entity -- the one that is not being tracked -- resulting in a no-op. You then call savechanges and and BAM! `DbUpdateException` as EF attempts to update the entity you thought you deleted.

Comment: Hi, your answer is right but @Pawel is also right. The exception I have is not coming from Entity Framework. "[DbUpdateException: Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Name'.]" it's seem it try to update and since the Name column is not nullable it fails. I do not understand why it tries to update since I ask to delete. Any idea?

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins I agree with Pawel regarding the `DbUpdateException`, answer updated.

Comment: I debugged and nothing is in the local. Also, the entity is null for everything except the ID which is set to know which one to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you are seeing is not related to validation what you have is DbUpdateException and not a validation exception). The exception message says that then Name property of the entity being saved is null while the column in the database is not nullable. (If validation was turned on it you would probably get a validation error - is it why you were trying to disable it at all?)

Comment: You are right. Why does it updates? It should simply delete the entity. I do not want any update to this entity...

Comment: I don't know. This code is doing more than "simply delete the entity" - there seem to be 2 objects involved - entity and the one you potentially found in local (not sure why this is needed anyways). You also expect that some entities are being tracked and I the exception can be caused by one of those and not the one you are trying to delete.

Comment: Everything is at null http://imgur.com/tatHhfu no FK link to this entity neither since it's a new entity.

Comment: My guess is that your Name property is a ComplexType, which needs to hold a value.